# Sum of a sequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, summation-method

I would like to find the value of

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{r=1}^n \frac{r}{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7\cdots(2r+1)}.$$

My approach is attached below.

[image: My approach ( click here )]

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Is it mandatory to use MathJax?

Comment: It is much preferred to use MathJax when possible.  Images can't be browsed and aren't accessible to those using screen readers, for example.

Comment: Oh sorry. I am new to this and i am not used to MathJax. I tried my best and made the question using it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Now note that $\sum_{r=1}^n (T(r-1)-T(r))$ telescopes to $T(0)-T(n)$.

Comment: Can you please explain how?

Comment: Write out the first several terms and notice the pairs that appear with opposite signs.

Comment: Finally I noticed it. Thanks mate!